# Extracted from intent parameters are not getting assigned to variables after parsing JSON from API call

Tags: javascript, json, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm getting JSON from a website. When I print with `console.log()` all is good(I see the needed data printed) but the parameters passed via Intent are not getting assigned to variable which later i'm putting in export so the Google Assistant tell me the info.

What am I doing wrong?  The code below is a Google Cloud Function running in Dialogflow.

```js
'use strict';

//This is what I say to get info out
//"Bus line 409 , bus stop nutrio bar"

const request = require('request');
let url = 'https://www.SAMPLESITE.com/Ajax/FindStationDevices?stationId=';

//Creating variables with sample data, that I'm always getting but not the real-time data from JSON.
var arriveInG = "15:15";
var delayG = "7:07";
var arriveTimeG = "13:44";
var distanceLeftG = "2.3 km";

// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

// Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'blah-blah'.
// The intent collects a parameters named 'busline,busStop'.
app.intent('getBusTime', (conv, params) => {
    const bLine = params.busline;
    const bStop = params.busStop;

    url+= bStop;

    // These are to tell me if parameters are extracted correctly.
    // conv.ask('Your lucky number is '  + bLine);
    // conv.close(`You said ${num}`);
    // conv.ask('Bus Stop is: '  + bStop + " ");
    // conv.ask(' Bus Line is: '  + bLine);
    // conv.ask(' URL is: '  + url);

    request.get({
        url: url,
        json: true,
        headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
      },(err, res, data) => {
        
        if (err) {
    
          console.log('Error:', err);
    
        } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
    
          console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
    
        } else {
          // do something here with received data

          // data is already parsed as JSON:
          // console.log(data.schedule[0].data[0].text);
  
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < data.liveData.length; i++) { //
              //Check if Live data is not null
              if (data.liveData[i] !== null) {
                //If bus line is the correct one from our question then...
                if (data.liveData[i].allLines[0] == bLine) {

                  arriveInG = data.liveData[i].arriveIn;
                  arriveTimeG = data.liveData[i].arriveTime;
                  delayG = data.liveData[i].delay;
                  distanceLeftG = data.liveData[i].distanceLeft;

                  console.log("Bus Line number " + bLine + 
                              " on Bus Stop " + bStop +  
                              " will arrive in " + arriveInG);
                              
                  console.log("The arrive time is " + arriveTimeG);
                  console.log("Distance left is " + distanceLeftG);
                  
                  assingValues(arriveInG);
                }
                 
              } else {
                 console.log("data.liveData[0] != null");
              }
          }
        }  
    }); 
    
    conv.ask(" Bus Line number " + bLine
        + " on Bus Stop " + bStop
        + " will arrive in " + arriveInG
        + ".The arrive time is " + arriveTimeG
        + ".Distance left is " + distanceLeftG); 
});

function assingValues(arrival) 
{
    arriveInG = arrival;
}

// Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And the working code after help from Prisoner is this:

```js
'use strict';

const request = require('request');
const requestNat = require('request-promise-native');

let url = 'https://www.samplewebsite.com/Ajax/FindStationDevices?stationId=';
var arriveInG = "15:15";//sample inital values assigned.
var delayG = "7:07";//sample inital values assigned.
var arriveTimeG = "13:44";//sample inital values assigned.
var distanceLeftG = "2.3 km";//sample inital values assigned.

// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

// Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'getBusTime'.
// The intent collects a parameter named 'busline', 'busStop'.
app.intent('getBusTime', (conv, params) => {
    const bLine = params.busline;
    const bStop = params.busStop;

    url+= bStop;

    return requestNat.get({
      url: url,
      json: true,
      headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
    }).then( body => {
    
      // Process the body, which is already an object
      // console.log(data.schedule[0].data[0].text);

      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < body.liveData.length; i++) { //
          //Check if Live data is not null
          if (body.liveData[i] !== null) {
            //If bus line is the correct one from our qustion then...
            if (body.liveData[i].allLines[0] == bLine) {

              arriveInG = body.liveData[i].arriveIn;
              arriveTimeG = body.liveData[i].arriveTime;
              delayG = body.liveData[i].delay;
              distanceLeftG = body.liveData[i].distanceLeft;
              console.log("Bus Line number " + bLine + 
                          " on Bus Stop " + bStop +  
                          " will arrive in " + arriveInG);
              console.log("The arrive time is " + arriveTimeG);
              console.log("Distance left is " + distanceLeftG);
            }
             
          } else {
             console.log("data.liveData[0] != null");
          }   
      }

      //Place the google assistant answer here
      conv.ask(" Bus Line number " + bLine
      + " on Bus Stop " + bStop
      + " will arrive in " + arriveInG
      + ".The arrive time is " + arriveTimeG
      + ".Distance left is " + distanceLeftG);

    }).catch( err => {
      // Error handling
      console.log('Error:', err);
    });
});



// Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);

    // TO TEST Respond individually(put in body !!!)
    // conv.ask('Your lucky number is '  + bLine);
    // conv.close(`You said ${num}`);
    // conv.ask('Bus Stop is: '  + bStop + " ");
    // conv.ask(' Bus Line is: '  + bLine);
    // conv.ask(' URL is: '  + url);
    
    // Test Speach
    // Bus line 409 , bus stop nutrio bar
    // Bus line 148 , bus stop 53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two related problems here.

The first is that if you are doing asynchronous calls, your handler must return a Promise. Otherwise the library does not know when the asynchronous call is done, has the data, and you can send back a reply.

Since you are making an HTTP call, this is an async request, and thus needs to be done using a Promise. The easiest way to do this is to use the [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) package instead of the `request` package.

So that part of the code might look something like this:

```
const request = require('request');
return request.get({
  url: url,
  json: true,
  headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
}).then( body => {
  // Process the body, which is already an object
}).catch( err => {
  // Error handling
});
```

The second problem is that your call to `conv.ask()` is outside the callback function with the response. In the code above, it should be in the part where it says "Process the body".

Comment: Hey Prisoner Thanks it's working like a charm, God Bless... !